# Python random.seed produces similar random.randint numbers in python given different range sizes

Tags: python, random

When using `random` in python, there are certain seeds that produce similar random numbers.

For example in python 3.8.5:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(100)
>>> print(random.randint(1,100))
19
>>> random.seed(335)
>>> print(random.randint(1,100))
19
>>> random.seed(100)
>>> print(random.randint(1,500))
75
>>> random.seed(335)
>>> print(random.randint(1,500))
75
>>> random.seed(100)
>>> print(random.randint(1,1000))
150
>>> random.seed(335)
>>> print(random.randint(1,1000))
149
```

It would appear that this pattern holds for many combinations of seeds where making random.randint produce similar results for different seeds.

For another example:

```
>>> import random
>>> random.seed(101)
>>> print(random.randint(1,100))
75
>>> random.seed(155)
>>> print(random.randint(1,100))
75
>>> random.seed(101)
>>> print(random.randint(1,500))
298
>>> random.seed(155)
>>> print(random.randint(1,500))
298
>>> random.seed(101)
>>> print(random.randint(1,1000))
596
>>> random.seed(155)
>>> print(random.randint(1,1000))
595
```

Is there any reasonably simple way to solve this such that these numbers produce substantially different results given different range sizes?

Comment: So your question is how to pick the seeds or how to pick the ranges?

Comment: The question is how to seed appropriately such that given an arbitrary range size, two seeds that generate similar results with one range size will generate substantially different results with another.

Answer (score 1):

It's simply due to the fact that their `random.random()` results are very similar:

```py
random.seed(100)
random.random() # 0.1456692551041303

random.seed(335)
random.random() # 0.14455004782209402
```

The easiest way is to just not generate only one random number the seeds, since they start to differ again after generating a random number. But, if you really wanted to generate different numbers depending on the range size, you could do something where you seed the rng with the seed multiplied by the range size.